# Application of the recursion theorem

Tags: logic, computability, recursion

Let $\langle\phi_{e} \mid e \in \omega\rangle $ be some standard enumeration of partial recursive functions. Show that there is some index $e \in \omega$, such that $f=\phi_{e}$ is a total function and $f^{n}=\phi_{f(n)}$ (where $f^{n}$ denotes composing $f$ with itself $n$-times).

I guess that trying to copy the proof of the recursion theorem the result should follow. Any hint will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably less silly ways to do this, but:

By the recursion theorem, we can find some $e$ such that $\varphi_e$ is the constant function "$x\mapsto e$." *(This is often presented as the first application of the theorem. If you haven't seen this before, do you see how to show this?)*

Now take $f=\varphi_e$. We have $f^n=f$ and $\varphi_{f(n)}\cong\varphi_e\cong f$ for all $n$.

---

Actually, strictly speaking the above doesn't work when we take $n=0$: $f^0$ should be defined as the identity, regardless of what $f$ is. To remedy this, we ask instead for an index $e$ such that

- $\varphi_e(0)$ is an index for the identity function, and
- $\varphi_e(n+1)=e$.

Take $f=\varphi_e$; we now get $f^0=id=\varphi_{f(0)}$, $f^{n+1}: x\mapsto e$, and $\varphi_{f(n+1)}: x\mapsto e$ as desired.

Comment: I did not realize how easy it was! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate another method. If $h(x,y,z)$ is defined by
$$\begin{align*}
h(x, 0, z) &= z \\
h(x, y+1, z) &= \phi_x(h(x, y, z))
\end{align*}$$
then it's partial recursive, so by the s-m-n theorem there's a recursive $g(x, y)$ with $\phi_{g(x, y)}(z) = h(x, y, z).$
By the same theorem there's a recursive $k(x)$ with $\phi_{k(x)}(y) = g(x, y).$

Now apply the recursion theorem to obtain a fixed $e$ with $\phi_e = \phi_{k(e)} = f.$

Clearly $f$ is total because $g$ is total and $f(y) = g(e, y).$ Furthermore, $$
\begin{align*}
f^y(z) &= \phi_e^y(z) \\
&= h(e, y, z) \\
&= \phi_{g(e, y)}(z) \\
&= \phi_{f(y)}(z)
\end{align*}$$
As desired.